# How to automatically compile scss into css with assets pipeline in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, asset-pipeline

The new rails 3.1 asset pipeline confused me a lot. In rails 3.0.x, with the sass gem, my global css file got updated when I edit .scss files. But in rails 3.1, that doesn't work anymore. It seems like I have to run a rake task to update my css files whenever I modify the .scss files. I feel like I misunderstand something about the new asset pipeline, but I don't know what it is. Can someone provide a solution or explanation to this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two possible causes of this. I am assuming that you are in development mode, and that all the gems are loaded.

**1. Config**

In development mode files are compiled on-demand and cached until any changes are made. You have to get the new 3.1 config options set in the right files or this might not work as expected.

Check out the Rails guides section on [upgrading](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#upgrading-from-old-versions-of-rails).

**2. Extensions**

The other is getting the extensions in the right order. For scss that would be `file.css.scss`. This tells Sprockets to parse the files as scss first, and that the have a css extension. If you had .erb on the end - `file.css.scss.erb` -  then erb is processed first, then scss.

Upgrading apps is a bit tricky because so many things have changed. The [asset pipeline guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) has lots of useful information and advice.

Comment: I'd like to say I have followed the steps in the guide and I still need to compile my assets in development for the changes to CSS to take effect. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check that the settings in your config files match those in the asset pipeline guide. Then delete the asset directory in public on dev and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Sass / SCSS has this built in already so you don't have to do ERB pre-processing.

```
image-url("image.png")
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets

Answer (score 0):

For me this problem resolved very easy.
I simple deleted all precompiled *.css files from assets/stylesheets and remain all *.scss files. Rails worked fine with *.scss directly, withoutn precompile.